# default store view is not selected by deafult when open any category in magento 2 admin

Tags: admin-panel, store-view, magento2.3.0, category-tree

I have migrated Magento 1.9.3.1 to Magento 2.3.0

I am getting an issue in the admin.

When I open category in admin side then **English** store is selected by default. How can I make **default_store_view** is selected by default?

Also **Add Root Category** & **Add Subcategory** buttons are missing in the admin.

How can I fix these issues? Can anyone suggest a solution?